# How to dynamically show number of products in a row according to browser size?

Tags: css, layout

[image]

In an ecommerce site, I would like to display number of items in a row according to browser width, but minimum will be 4 items. Just like what has been done in Amozon site, if you try to browse amozon.com, try to maximize and shrink your browser, you will find that number of items display in [More Items to Consider] section is according to your browser size. It is smart enough to know when it should fully hide or show an item, no partially visible item forever.

Anyone know what is this technology called? Any idea how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `float` elements in a `div` with `overflow:hidden`. I'll jsfiddle a proof of concept for you.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WLEzw/

Make your browser window bigger and smaller and you will see more and less pears.

Comment: Thanks. But what if items are displayed with table not div?

Comment: Then it's not possible because a table explicitly defines the number of items on a row, namely the number of `td` elements within the `tr`. Using table is a bad choice here anyway, because you are not handling tabular data. Can you not change it to a `div`?

Answer (score 0):

That is just CSS based.

An example of what you want to accomplish from a friend [website redesign](http://joaoramos.org/labs/redesign/)

shrink and wide the browser so you can see the effect

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JQuery to moniter whether browser window is resized, through `$(window).resize` function. And you'll have to call details of the products shown either using Ajax or with iframe by reloading the page within iframe with more products.

The code to be written inside browser's resize method will be as follows.

```
 $(window).resize(function() {

      //Your code on resizing the browser.

 });
```

Comment: there is no `js` nor `jquery` tag on the question. Also, it seems like a lot of overhead to use jquery for something that can be done by pure css.

Comment: @Bazzz: but getting it done "cross-browser" is rather more important than end-up with CSS that is only supported by a few versions of a few browsers. :-)

Comment: Agree in some cases. But fortunately in this case `float` and `overflow` are supported by all major browsers in all major versions. Indeed a few archaic browsers might not support it, but in the end one shouldn't be using those browsers anyway for reasons beyond simple css support.