# Set number of products in a row according to screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set my number of products in a row according to the screen width.i.e on normal screen it would be 3 in a row .then on large screen it would be 4 on extra large screen it would be 5 and so on.I have checked a couple of solution but they did't work some are [Stackoverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375165/how-to-dynamically-show-number-of-products-in-a-row-according-to-browser-size) [stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558882/change-number-of-products-in-a-row-on-category-view-in-opencart-2-x)
outer container width is fixed i.e 1328 px.I am using bootstrap.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="col-md-2">
          //categories sidebar
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-8">
          //categories sidebar
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
           //categories sidebar
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using multiples of 12, that's easy with bootstrap:

http://www.bootply.com/F5yisSxsQm

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to use a .row class between the .container and .col-md-* so you don't have margin issues.

Answer (score 1):

For non-Bootstrap cases - [use CSS media queries.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Example:

```
.container {
    width: 1328px;
}
.container .column {
    width: 33%; /* 3 per-row */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .container .column {
        width: 20%; /* 5 per-row */
    }
}
```

For Bootstrap 3.x.x, you can use the same approach you are currently with some added classes. `col-md-*` classes are for medium-sized desktop screens, but you can also use `col-xs-*`, `col-sm-*` and `col-lg-*` alongside it for (according to documentation) phone, tablet and large-desktop sized screens respectively.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          //categories sidebar
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-4">
          //categories sidebar
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
           //categories sidebar
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-4">
          //added column - wraps around to a new row on non-large screens
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```